# Retrieve prefixes from Google firebase storage files

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the below to retrieve prefixes from a reference to a google firebase storage bucket list of files...but when I console.log the prefixes they are not logging.

I want `console.log("PREFIXES" + foldeRef);` to display the prefixes, but foldeRef does not return anything it appears.

```
const getNewImages = () => {
    
    const listRef = storageRef
      .child("users")
      .child("H7pFwl0uuRV1NMt8y55S42hxpTi2");
    
    // Find all the prefixes and items.
    listRef
      .listAll()
      .then((res) => {
       
        res.prefixes.forEach((foldeRef) => {
          const PREFIX = foldeRef.listAll();
         
          console.log("PREFIXES" + foldeRef);

          // All the prefixes under listRef.
          // You may call listAll() recursively on them.
        });
        res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
          console.log("Items " + itemRef);

          array.push(itemRef);
          // All the items under listRef.
          //console.log('ARRAY'+array);
          //setTestImage(array);
          //console.log("TEST IMAGE  " + array);

          
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("ERROR" + error);
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      });
  };
```

Comment: Does itemRef return anything? Do you get any errors at all?

Comment: itemRef returns the link to the image in my firebase storage i.e " gs://....." but in this case I am not useing that I just put it there for reference. I am also not receiving any errors. I actually solved this just now a different way by accessing the image URL.name but Im still curious as to why the prefixes arent being accessed.

Comment: Hello again, sorry for the late response. But in testing with the [API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) that is listed as [what firestore uses](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files), I've noticed that the prefixes array's values are actually of the subfolders contained within and not the full prefix/path. So it would seem that it's intended to dive further into the bucket rather than describe the full reference to the file. I believe [name](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#file_metadata_properties) is what you want.

Comment: yep, that's what I ended up figuring out. I accessed the URL.name of each returned item instead...thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit slow on the uptake sometimes and need to look at it myself before realizing what you were saying. Would you mind posting the solution you found in an answer and accepting it? (for visibility reasons) I'd do it myself, but that feels like taking unwarranted credit.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling upon this as they are encountering the same issue, `itemRef` (which is to say the individual entries in the response list obtained from [`listAll`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files)) lists the entire link to the item in question, to get the file's name it's best to use the file metadata value [`name`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#file_metadata_properties).

The reason for this is that [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/storage), which is the underlying technology behind [Firebase's Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage), [uses a flat namespace to store objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#object-names) and that means that, from the server's perspective, there are no folders or hierarchical structure, just files and permissions, the use of `/` as a separator is for user convenience and sorting.